# copyclip board with random color generator

Tags: javascript, html, css

im in the process of taking two projects that i found on instagram. i am making a random color generator and on the side of the text it shows a clipboard button so i can or who ever can randomly generate a color and copy the hex code. i have went over the code and both projects and i am getting a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'select' of null " in the console.

the project can be found at the following link https://codepen.io/nhmalbone0311/pen/KKmYQbQ.

```js
let letters = "0123456789ABCDEF";
const body = document.querySelector("body");
const colorElement = document.querySelector("#color");

function getColor() {
  let color = "#";
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
  }
  body.style.backgroundColor = color;
  colorElement.innerHTML = color;
}

function copyText() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("#color");
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  document.getElementById("notification").style.opacity = "1";
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.getElementById("notification").style.opacity = "0";
  }, 1000);
}

console.log(copyText);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #494e6b;
  transition: 0.1s;
}


/* p field */

.colors {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 26px;
  padding: 10px 57px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
}


/* btns */

.btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50px;
  height: 47px;
  border: none;
  margin: 0 5px 0;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.g-color {
  padding: 5px 13px;
  border: 3px solid #111;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  transition: 100ms ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.g-color:hover {
  outline: none;
  color: red;
}

.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-item: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 180px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  bottom: 7rem;
  left: 14rem;
  color: #fff;
  background: #98878f;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s;
}

.tooltip:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  top: -8rem;
  right: 50px;
  background: #985e6d;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p id="color" class="colors">#</p>
  <button onclick="copyText()" class="btn"><i class="far fa-copy"></i></button>
  <div class="generate-color">
    <button onclick="getColor()" class="g-color">Generate Color</button>
  </div>
  <!-- notification -->
  <div class="tooltip" id="notifaction">
    <p>Text Copied!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

im using code pen as i do this as a hobby for now in its just easier for me to show my work off and have people me if i need it.

im just now working on getting out of tutorial hell and founding projects on the web in intergrading them into my own style and changing things up.

Answer (score 0):

remove the # from the "#color" in `var copyText = document.getElementById("#color");`

Comment: even though that you answer solves the issue, it should have not been given as an answer. Issues that are caused by a typo have no value for SO and are a reason for closure and removal ( not reproduciable or caused by a typo). Awarded points will be lost then anyways.

Comment: so if i do that then i get  a error of "Uncaught TypeError: copyText.select is not a function "

Comment: @tacoshy sorry, should I remove the answer?

Comment: @NelsonMalbone not sure, try logging variables (like copyText) to see if any are null or undefined

Comment: no, no need it is just a reminder for the next time.

Comment: i just console log copyText and in the console it just shows the function and the code along with it.

Comment: @NelsonMalbone it works fine if the hash is removed from your cdoepen (line 14). Only the hash from `getElementById` must be removed not from `querySelector`

Comment: @NelsonMalbone I think I figured it out, you have the same name for the function and the variable. and that causes the problem